# Origin of the surname "Hooker"?

Tags: etymology, names

[Wiktionary claims](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hooker#Proper_noun) that the surname Hooker is occupational:

> an occupation for a maker of hooks

This seems unlikely to me for several reasons. Were it true, one would expect there to be a corresponding occupational term *hooker* in the OED — but there is not.  The OED gives "hooker" = petty thief back to the 16th century, and "hooker" = prostitute back to the mid-19th, but nothing about makers of hooks.

The name itself goes back at least to the 16th century.  For example, [Richard Hooker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hooker).  The name "Hooke" might be related.

Is anything known about this surname?  Surely it doesn't mean a petty thief or a prostitute.  Perhaps a variant spelling of *hawker*?  (The [OED has no evidence](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/88288) of such a spelling, however.)

Comment: Your local library may have a dictionary of surnames. There doesn't appear to be one available online.

Comment: I would suspect (OED) † **hucker**, n. Forms:  In Middle English hukker. -- Etymology: < huck v. + -er suffix1, or back-formation < huckster n. ... Obsolete. rare. -- **A petty dealer; one who bargains or haggles.** 14..   in T. Wright & R. P. Wülcker Anglo-Saxon & Old Eng. Vocab. (1884) I. 566/37   *Auccionator et Auccionatrix, an hukker & an hukkester.*

Comment: @Greybeard I didn't see this before I wrote my answer, but I followed a similar trail via the Middle English Dictionary.

Comment: Most Anglophone countries have always received a *lot* of immigrants. Many if not most of whom will "Anglicise" their names. Any immigrant whose "native" name sounds anything like **hʊkə** would be quite likely to end up writing it as **Hooker** (and/or allowing/encouraging *native Anglophones* to write it like that) without knowing or caring about the meaning.

Comment: Could it be someone from a family line renown for [playing Rugby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooker_(rugby_league))?

Comment: "Surely it doesn't mean a petty thief or a prostitute." *looks at all the roads in the UK whose names essentially boil down to "Prostitute Street" because they used to be red-light districts* I dunno, it seems possible to me.

Comment: Alas, I thought I had read that the prostitute sense of "hooker" was related to General Joseph Hooker, but his [Wikipedia article has a paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Hooker#Legacy) debunking that particular folk etymology.

Comment: wiktionary is not a reference

Comment: "hooker" (prostitute) is very recent

Answer (score 6):

[Surname Database](https://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Hooks) suggests three possible sources [bolding mine; minor adjustments. While naming often stretches logic nowadays and is, I'd say, usually off-topic as with song lyrics, I'd say this involves legitimate etymology]:

> **Hooks**:
>
> Recorded as *Hook, Hooke, **Hooker**, Hookes, Hooks, Huck, Huke, Hocke* and
> *Huckes*, this is a very early English medieval surname,
> perhaps even the earliest – or certainly one of that select group. It
> has three possible origins, although none are directly connnected with
> piracy or the sea, not even the Hook of Holland!
>
> - The first is locational from one of various places called Hook or Hooke (Old English ''hoc'') in six English counties.
> - The second was a very popular nickname for a person with a hooked nose, and also originally ''hoc'', whilst
> - the third is from the pre 7th century Olde English ''hocere'', the later ''hooker,'' and occupational for a skilled maker of hooks. These
>   were not initially made from iron or steel, but fashioned using
>   heating and steaming from animal bone.
>
> The modern meaning of a call girl or boy, we understand is 19th
> century, and based upon ''hooking'' a person. To our knowledge it has
> no relevance to the origins of the surname – but anything is possible
> with surnames. Early examples of recordings include one *Halwun Hoce*
> in the register of Old English Bynames from the years 1050 - 1071 CE.
> As surnames are generally accepted as commencing in the three
> centuries AFTER the Norman Invasion of England in 1066, this means it
> really is old. Other very early examples include *Geoffrey de la Hoke*
> in the county of Devonshire in 1242, and *Gervase ad Hokys* of
> Bedfordshire in 1244, both are locational, whilst *John Hook* of Essex
> in 1327 is clearly a nickname. The very first known recording of all
> was that of *Osmundus Hocere*, in the rolls known as the Liber
> Elliensis of circa 975 CE. Surname holders have been granted at least
> twenty coats of arms. Perhaps the first is that of *Sir Richard Hook*,
> of the city of York, who served under King Edward 1st of England (1273 - 1307)....

Comment: Thanks!  The OED doesn't support "hocere" in connection with hooks or hookmaking.  [The only meaning it gives](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87666) is related to contempt or scorn.

Comment: The OED isn't comprehensive. The snag is, most other sources aren't as well edited.

Comment: Oy, even discussing and dismissing the streetwalker misassociation is horrifying as a patently false friend. Just saying, does Biden bide his time, or was Truss supportive?

Comment: OP _does_ ask (in a hedged way) about the possibility, Yosef. And some insults _were_ 'adopted' as surnames [[James Pylant; Genealogy Magazine](https://www.genealogymagazine.com/surnames-originating-as-insults/)].

Comment: I didn't ask. The history is clearly wrong because the streetwalker meaning is much too recent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Valid link. Maybe Abigail Van Buren got royalties from moving companies.

Comment: Well spotted, Edwin - I hadn't come across that website.

Comment: @Mark 'Surely' + declarative sentence structure looks very like a declarative question to me, question mark or not. //// I know nothing of the reputability of the site, Kate. But it looks well written.

Comment: The University of Toronto Dictionary and Corpus of Old English also doesn't mention anything like _hocere_ except in connection with contempt or scorn.  How reliable is this "Surname Database" website?  Is there any reason to think they didn't just make it up?

Answer (score 5):

One possibility not represented in the other answer relates to the [Middle English *hukker*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED21431) (comp. Middle Low German *hoker* and Middle Dutch *hoeker*; think modern *hawker*). Basically, a *Hooker* or *Hucker* could come from someone who peddled or auctioned goods. From the Middle English Dictionary:

> (a) A petty merchant, peddler, male huckster; ?also, an auctioneer; (b) in surnames.

Examples include

- Adam le Huckere de Saunford
- Joh. Le Hukker
- Richard le Uckermon
- Rob. Le Hockar
- Nicholaus le Hukker

The surnames include examples that could morph into *Hooker* by switching the [u] or [o] to [oo] and reducing the double letter [kk]. Both spelling changes are plausible between Middle English and Modern English, perhaps even by the time John Hooker was active in the 16th century ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hooker_(English_constitutionalist))). (Compare Middle English spellings of *buke* or *buk* to modern *book*.)  Also, one can find genealogical entries where siblings go by both "Hooker" and "Hucker," suggesting possible fluidity between the two spellings ([Ancestry.com](https://www.ancestry.com/genealogy/records/john-hooker-hucker-24-9qc18); [WikiTree](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Hucker-356)).

Comment: Thanks!  This sense of "hawker" goes back at least to the 1500s.

Comment: "Hooky" is also slang for stolen goods.